# Loop inside a element with a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below HTML. Can someone please tell me how I can loop through all the `div`s with the class `"tab-pane"` and see if any element inside the `div` has a class 
`"input-validation-error"` and then just change the background color of that `div`.

In this example the first `div` and the third `div` with `"tab pane"` class should have their background property change. I know how to loop through each but not sure how to look for specific properties inside child elements.

```
  <ul id="sellerAppTabs">
                            <li title="General Information"><a href="#tab" data-toggle="tab">Section I</a></li>
                            <li title="Affiliate Information"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section II</a></li> 
<li title="Affiliate Information"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section II</a></li> 
                        </ul>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab">
<div class="test1">
<h1>Some Data</h1>
<input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
<input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
<div class="test2">
<h1>Some Data</h1>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
</div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
<div class="test1">
<h1>Some Data</h1>
<input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
<input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
</div>
</div>
```

So I have to loop through the `a` tags in the sellerAppTabs `ul` section which have their `id`s matched to the `div`s and then if the `div` has any `"input-validation-error"` class then I have to change the background color of the `li` above the `a` tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) or [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

```js
$('.tab-pane').has('.input-validation-error').css({background: '#C55'})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane">
 <div class="test1">
  <h1>Some Data</h1>
  <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
  <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane">
 <div class="test2">
  <h1>Some Data</h1>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane">
 <div class="test1">
  <h1>Some Data</h1>
  <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
  <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to loop. Just use a :has() selector

```
$('.tab-pane:has(.input-validation-error)').css('background', 'red');
```

```js
$('.tab-pane:has(.input-validation-error)').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane">
  <div class="test1">
    <h1>Some Data</h1>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
    </input>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
    </input>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane">
  <div class="test2">
    <h1>Some Data</h1>
    <input type="text">
    </input>
    <input type="text">
    </input>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane">
  <div class="test1">
    <h1>Some Data</h1>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
    </input>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error">
    </input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('input-validation-error');

for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
    if( els[x].value == '' ){

        els[x].parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, a simple `.each()` function would suffice. Followed by `.find()` for the input validation class

```
$('.tab-pane').each(function(){
    $(this).find('.input-validation-error').each(function() {
        //change the color
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `each` and `find`:

```
$(".tab-pane").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find(".input-validation.error")) {
        // $(this) points to the div.tab-pane!
        $(this).css("background-color", "red")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the elements with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
2. Filter the desired elements with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
3. Iterate with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
[].filter.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane'),
  function(elem) { return elem.querySelector('.input-validation-error'); }
).forEach(function(elem) { elem.style.backgroundColor = color; });
```

```js
[].filter.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane'),
  function(elem) { return elem.querySelector('.input-validation-error'); }
).forEach(function(elem) { elem.style.backgroundColor = '#C55'; });
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane">
  <div class="test1">
    <h1>Some Data</h1>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error"/>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
  <div class="test2">
    <h1>Some Data</h1>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane">
  <div class="test1">
    <h1>Some Data</h1>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error"/>
    <input type="text" class="input-validation-error"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery filter functionality:

```
$('.tab-pane')
  .filter(':has(.input-validation-error)');
  .css('background', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and stick with [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) by using [`getElementsByClassName()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a list of elements of which you can iterate through for your operations.